# "navigator.getDeviceStorage is not a function" error in Open Web App on Desktop

Tags: firefox, web-applications, firefox-os

I wrote Firefox OS app and want to use it on Android and Desktop.
The problem is that on both this platforms I have the same error:

`navigator.getDeviceStorage is not a function`

While it works perfectly in emulator, and (according to reviews) on real device too.
App in Firefox Marketplace: https://marketplace.firefox.com/app/cleverstyle-music/
Source code on GitHub: https://github.com/nazar-pc/CleverStyle-Music

Looks like this is a bug in Firefox, because it doesn't ask for special permission for access to music library on Android.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.10 x64 and Firefox Nightly 33 (since 31 stable have some bug and app doesn't start more than once properly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not implemented yet, see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=886627 for the Android case (will be available in Firefox for Android 34) and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1046258 for the desktop case (no ETA).